# Creating a macro that copies certain cells and places them into columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have 26 worksheets every week that contain a "Station #", "Latitude#", and a "Longitude#". 
I want to create a Macro that grabs these 3 cells, copies them and places them into 3 columns named "Station #", "Lat", and "Long. 
I'm not very good at this so i need some help. 
This is what i got so far:

```
Sub Macro1()

FolderName = "C:\Users\Captain Wypij\Desktop\Traffic\test"
If Right(FolderName, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then FolderName = FolderName & Application.PathSeparator
Fname = Dir(FolderName & "*.xls")

    'loop through the files
Do While Len(Fname)

    With Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Fname)

Range("C8:D8").Select
Selection.Copy
ChDir "C:\Users\Captain Wypij\Desktop\Traffic"
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Captain Wypij\Desktop\Traffic\Test.xls.xlsx"
Range("A2").Select
If ("A2") = "*" Then Range("A3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Workbooks.Open (FolderName & Fname)
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
Range("C34:D34").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Test.xls.xlsx").Activate
Range("B2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Workbooks.Open (FolderName & Fname)
Range("G34:H34").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Test.xls.xlsx").Activate
Range("C2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Workbooks.Open (FolderName & Fname)
 ActiveWindow.Close

 Windows("Test.xls.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close

End With
    ' go to the next file in the folder
    Fname = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

I cant seem to figure out how to paste the next worksheet i open in the next fields ( such as A3, B3, C3 and so forth. 
Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim FolderName As String, Fname As Variant
FolderName = "C:\Location\Folder\"
Fname = Dir(FolderName & "*.xlsx")
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, lr as long

Do While Fname <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Fname)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("SheetName") '~~> Change to suit
    With Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '~~> Change to suit
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws.Range("C8:D8").Copy: .Range("A" & lr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ws.Range("C34:D34").Copy: .Range("B" & lr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ws.Range("G34:H34").Copy: .Range("C" & lr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
    wb.Close False
    Set wb = Nothing: Set ws = Nothing
    Fname = Dir
Loop
```

Above code basically opens all *.xlsx* file in the specified folder and then copies static ranges.
 This static ranges are the ones you specified in your question (e.g. `Range("C8:D8")`).
 So it copies it and paste it as values on the sheet you will specify.
 It finds the last row on the destination sheet which will put the copied values below it.
Is this what you're trying? HTH.